# Select value from table based dropdown : Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am scrapping some data from this [platform](http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels). To perform actions, i am using browser simulation tool selenium with python. I want to select drop-down value from a menu but it has been developed as a table, so i am not able to select the element right way. Details are mentioned below:

[image: Element to be selected]

The HTML of the element is here :

```
<table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitDownArrowButton dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode,_popupStateNode" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Select_0" widgetid="dijit_form_Select_0" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" style="user-select: none;" popupactive="true" aria-owns="dijit_form_Select_0_menu"><tbody role="presentation"><tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span role="option" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">Active EPA/LA (239)</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="Active EPA/LA" aria-hidden="true"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><span class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner"></span></td></tr></tbody></table>

<tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span `role="option" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">Active EPA/LA (239)</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="Active EPA/LA" aria-hidden="true"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><span class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner"></span></td></tr>`
```

The approach i am using:

```
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import shutil
import uuid

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


class crawlOcean():

    def __init__(self):
        print("hurray33")
        global downloadDir
        downloadDir = ""

        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir)
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                          "attachment/csv")
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("hurray")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.driver.get("http://www.epa.ie/hydronet/#Water%20Levels")
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def crawl(self):
        print("see")
        driver = self.driver
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 800)")
        driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_MenuItem_3_text").click()
        select = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Station status by owner:'])[1]/following::td[2]")
        select.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = crawlOcean()
    obj.crawl()
```

can any one help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to select required value:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="All"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[.="Active EPA/LA (239)"]').click()
```